# Can I create an sqlite3 connectiton without a file in Python?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a bytestring that holds the contents of a valid sqlite3 database. I have to save this bytestring to a file and call:

```
conn=sqlite3.connect("FILE_NAME")
```

I would rather not have to save this string to a file because I already have it in memory. Is there any way to create the connection object without this intermediate step?

Thanks.

This is Python 3.

Comment: *If* your version of sqlite was built with support for it, and *if* the python sqlite bindings provide it, there's [sqlite3_deserialize()](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/deserialize.html) to get an in-memory database handle. Those are pretty big ifs though. I wouldn't depend on it unless you're using C or C++ and can easily embed the sqlite source directly in your program and compile it with the appropriate option turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot. There are various ways to use a in memory database, either with a memory file system, or with the special database `':memory:'`. But in either case, the database is an opaque object that is known only by its *Connection* object, and you can neither (easily) load or store it.

The best I can imagine with a memory file system is to use it to write the byte string in a *memory* file, and let sqlite use it. That way nothing has been writen on disk, but you have not really accessed directly the byte string....

Comment: Thanks, I'll just save it to a file like I have been doing.

Comment: That's `:memory:` with colons on either end.